# What could be best way to reduce redundant code

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I wanted to reduce repetition in this code which I got from ExDeveloper. I have a server model where I've all my networking code. Now I've just shown 3 methods here. But eventually it'll grow & there would be 70+ methods. I don't want to repeat task code which is common in all methods.

What is the best way to do it without using a 3rd party like Alamofire, etc.?

```
func login(userName: String, password: String, onSuccess: @escaping(JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void){
    let url : String = ""
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            onFailure(error!)
        } else{
            print(response as Any)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}

//====================

func signUp(userName: String, password: String, email: String, onSuccess: @escaping(JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void){
    let url : String = ""
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            onFailure(error!)
        } else{
            print(response as Any)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}

//====================


func forgot(email: String, onSuccess: @escaping(JSON) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void){
    let url : String = ""
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            onFailure(error!)
        } else{
            print(response as Any)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Why would you not use Alamofire when it does what you want?

Comment: For legitimate, robust networking in Swift, where you need to handle things like percent escaping, Alamofire would be my first choice. I try to avoid third-party modules whenever I can but Alamofire is not one of them.

Comment: The example is not very meaningful because the parameters are not used at all. By the way: A GET request does not require an `URLRequest`. Just pass the URL. And don't use `NSMutable...` classes and `NSURL` in Swift at all. This avoids the ugly bridge casting.

Comment: @vadian Sir please give me a link to file which has the best practice to write Network module for any web-based app.

Comment: There is no 'best practice', it completely depends on your app.

Comment: @RAISIQBAL, as you claim to be a software architect on you profile, you should at least know how to move equal or similar code to secondary functions and call them were needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could split up the requests into more modular components like network layers.

Check out this guide: https://medium.com/@danielemargutti/network-layers-in-swift-7fc5628ff789

Answer (score 0):

As you've written the above code, each function is exactly identical. So put that in a separate function that they all call. If there are parts that aren't identical (that you didn't provide), then pass those to the shared function. If there is code that changes, pass that as a function parameter.

In short: extract the parts that don't change, and pass the parts that do as parameters.